# What are the chances for a scholarship winner to be denied admission at Uni?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding

If a student wins a scholarship (like the german DAAD scholarship, for example), does his chance for admission at an University to pursue a Masters degree increase?

Let's say he fulfilled all of the requirements for admission. On top of that, he won a scholarship that fully funds his studies. Would he be given advantage over other candidates that applied for the same MSc program?

Comment: Not sure why you deleted your other DAAD question. // Please don't pay any mind to what that participant said about how it was elementary to realize you should prepare for such a question. I find certain news topics too depressing to follow or think about.  Also, sometimes you need to focus 100% on your studies.  Additionally, sometimes family matters are wholly absorbing.  Etc. // If the DAAD folks are such jerks as to take political opinions into account in these decisions, they don't deserve to get any students. But I think that question was ...

Comment: ... icing on the cake.  They *can't* have been stupid enough to use that answer as the basis for a decision (unless your field were political science). // I wish you would undelete the question.  I would really like to know if what they did is allowed in the German system.

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks for the positive feedback; I agree completely. It is allowed I guess, since it shows that you are well rounded individual with opinions about different topics. And no, my chosen studies are not in political science; but in natural sciences. Question undeleted, greetings.

Comment: Thanks for restoring the [other question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/102474/32436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It very much depends on the admissions system. If the system is based (almost) strictly on grades (the way the German system largely is determined), then having a scholarship doesn't help with admissions. This is also the case if there are minimal tuition and registration fees associated with admission.

In the US, though, funding is a much more important issue in admissions. Students with their own funding source *definitely* have an advantage over other students *of comparable quality*, since they cost less money, and thereby can be admitted when other students can't. However, a student who has a scholarship but might not be a good fit for the department might not be admitted.